# Is there a way to run r on iOS device

Tags: ios, r

I'm looking for a solution to run some r scripts and display graphics on an iOs device using r. 
I saw this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/r-programming-language/id540809637?mt=8 but we can't plot graph with it.

I just need something really basic, but which allows me to test some computations when I have an idea.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but you could run an RStudio Server, then access it over the web in your preferred browser.

Comment: The only real way to do this is what @IanWesley suggested. Fire up a cloud instance and use mobile Safari. For some reason RStudio refuses to create even an iOS "shell" app that connects to a cloud instance so you're stuck with a pretty bad mobile browser experience.

Answer (score 1):

- [R Analyst](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/r-analyst/id1173749340?mt=8) runs R 3.1.5
- [Analyst](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/analyser/id1083042861) has both R and Python. It also includes some fill-in-the-blanks forms for simple analyses. (e.g. a mini-SAS PROC)

I believe the developer is working on a 3.5.x update.

Apple App store rules limit the full functionality of R. Due to App Store rules, neither App allows you to install packages with compiled binaries. The default packages (all 188 of them, including the `tidyverse` packages, `data.table`, and `knit`) are on a system path that is not writable without jailbreaking. However, you can source directories and `.libPath` is functional.

Both allow you to create PDF graphics directly, and to save the displayed graph as png and jpeg (IIRC). `knitr::spin` and `knit::stitch` work if you set the dev to pdf. I've yet to test `knitr::knit` and its variations.

Both support document sharing via iOS files app, so you can use iOS editors like Textastic, Buffer, and GoCoEdit to write your code, and Working Copy for git support.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried connecting to the RStudio server using chrome on my browser but the arrows don't work so it's not perfect.

I used the app Juno, to connect to Jupyter hub running R and it worked much better. The Microsoft azure service provides free "notebooks": notebooks.azure.com